# Reading religion column in 1906 Denmark Census image?

Tags: census-records, transcriptions, denmark

*For ease of answering I have split this question into 3 separate questions.*

Can anyone assist me to finish off reading the details of this 1906 Danish census?

[image: Per Kjeld Lassen 1906 Census, Denmark]

The image is from FamilySearch who cite it as:

> "Denmark Census, 1906," database with images, FamilySearch (https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:QLXW-Y5BS : 19 October 2017), Peter Kjeld Lassen in entry for Johan Chr Julius Zahle Lassen, København, Danmark; from "1906 Denmark Census," database and images, MyHeritage ( https://www.myheritage.com : 2016), film 00040; citing Rigsarkivet, København, Danmark (National Archives, Copenhagen, Denmark).

The column headings I have from the FS Wiki - there are apparently 3 formats and this is the Copenhagen format, although the place (Hellerup) is just outside the city of Copenhagen so far as I can see from maps.

I am interested in the Lassen family and using the index and image, I believe the names are:

- Johan Chr Julius Zahle-Lassen
- Thora Vilhelmine "
- Karen Margrethe "
- Kaj Erik "
- Per Kjeld "
- Yelva Helversen

The Lassen family's **Religion is in col 7 - any idea what this reads?**

Thanks for any assistance. (Incidentally, should you try and use the index to locate them in FS, be aware that Per has been indexed by MyHeritage and FS as Peter, which might(?) be a correct translation but is very naughty in my view.)

Comment: Don't be afraid to split this into four separate questions.  You may find that a potential answerer is holding off on answering any of them because they can only answer one or two of them so far.  Having separate questions provides additional scope for providing more detail in both each question and any answers to it.  Also, it helps our site stats to have more Q&As:-)

Comment: It looks like @aem might already have written an answer if the question about reading the Religion column (Q3) was not part of an omnibus.

Comment: I have split the original question into 3 separate StackExchange questions - this is the original URL and now only refers to the Religion, and 2 others have been raised - one for the occupations and one for the place-names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Religion_in_Denmark, the (Lutheran) state religion of Denmark is known as the Dansk Folkekirke. It looks like the religion column for all the heads of household could be an abbreviation of Folkekirke. I suspect if you look through other pages you'll see nearly everyone has that same entry for religion. (Note the other members of each household say "do", meaning ditto, indicating the same as the entry for the person above.)

See for instance a later image in the same collection, https://www.familysearch.org/ark:/61903/3:1:3Q9M-CSLM-M3Y2-8?i=453&cc=2800931, where the religion (column 7) of the head of the second household can be pretty easily read as "Folkekirke".

Comment: Thanks for that. I had wondered if the answer was "Lutheran" on statistical grounds, but the word clearly wasn't that. Now you've said that, it looks like "Folkek" to me, abbreviated from "Folkekirke".