# Reading occupation in 1906 Denmark Census image?

Tags: census-records, 1900s-decade, transcriptions, denmark

*This question has been split off from [Reading place names in 1906 Denmark Census image?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/15494/310)*

Can anyone assist me to finish off reading the details of this 1906 Danish census?

[image: Per Kjeld Lassen 1906 Census, Denmark]

The image is from FamilySearch who cite it as:

> "Denmark Census, 1906," database with images, FamilySearch (https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:QLXW-Y5BS : 19 October 2017), Peter Kjeld Lassen in entry for Johan Chr Julius Zahle Lassen, København, Danmark; from "1906 Denmark Census," database and images, MyHeritage ( https://www.myheritage.com : 2016), film 00040; citing Rigsarkivet, København, Danmark (National Archives, Copenhagen, Denmark).

The column headings I have from the FS Wiki - there are apparently 3 formats and this is the Copenhagen format, although the place (Hellerup) is just outside the city of Copenhagen so far as I can see from maps.

I am interested in the Lassen family and using the index and image, I believe the names are:

- Johan Chr Julius Zahle-Lassen
- Thora Vilhelmine "
- Karen Margrethe "
- Kaj Erik "
- Per Kjeld "
- Yelva Helversen

Re the occupations in col. 12
 - I believe that Johan is an Inspector but if anyone wants to dispute this, please do so. (Other trees suggest he worked as an inspector for an insurance company)

**Question - what is Yelva's occupation?** I'm guessing that she's a servant or maybe house-keeper but I can't find a word in Google Translate to match...

Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yelva is a *Husjomfru* (house-maid), i.e. a female servant in a "more familiarly position" according to [ODS](https://ordnet.dk/ods/ordbog?query=husjomfru&tab=for).

Comment: Thanks for that - I had managed to find the family in the 1901 Census where she was described as a "tyende", which I understand means "servant". So there's a subtle difference between 1901 and 1906.

Comment: You're welcome. *Tyende* is indeed "servant", but could easily be of a shorter term (half or whole year contracts were common). I suppose they had a good relationship.

Comment: Perhaps she doubled as a nanny of sorts, at the time usually called *gouvernante* (ie. governess) in Danish after the French, currently *barnepige* is the more common word.

Comment: Thanks for the insights - Yelva may very well have been a bit more than an ordinary domestic servant if she was with them for 5 years *and* she moved from Aarhus to Hellerup with the family.