# Reading place-names in 1906 Denmark Census image?

Tags: census-records, 1900s-decade, transcriptions, denmark

*This question has been split off from [Reading religion column in 1906 Denmark Census image?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/15494/310)*

Can anyone assist me to finish off reading the details of this 1906 Danish census?

[image: Per Kjeld Lassen 1906 Census, Denmark]

The image is from FamilySearch who cite it as:

> "Denmark Census, 1906," database with images, FamilySearch (https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:QLXW-Y5BS : 19 October 2017), Peter Kjeld Lassen in entry for Johan Chr Julius Zahle Lassen, København, Danmark; from "1906 Denmark Census," database and images, MyHeritage ( https://www.myheritage.com : 2016), film 00040; citing Rigsarkivet, København, Danmark (National Archives, Copenhagen, Denmark).

The column headings I have from the FS Wiki - there are apparently 3 formats and this is the Copenhagen format, although the place (Hellerup) is just outside the city of Copenhagen so far as I can see from maps.

I am interested in the Lassen family and using the index and image, I believe the names are:

- Johan Chr Julius Zahle-Lassen
- Thora Vilhelmine "
- Karen Margrethe "
- Kaj Erik "
- Per Kjeld "
- Yelva Helversen

Re the place-names in col.8 (birthplaces) and col.9 (where the family lived previously)

I believe that Johan is born in Korsør (this is written in other trees and it seems to match this)

I know that Per is born in Hellerup.

I know that the family moved into the area in 1902 - that's what column 10 says.

**Can anyone read the other birthplaces for the Lassen family in col. 8 and also the place where they moved here from (Col 9)?**

---

One reflection, there are only 2 unknown place-names here - given that I have Johan and Per's birthplace (and I'm not tracking Yelva). Thora's birth-place (beginning with V) is unknown and the birth-places for Karen and Kai are the same, unknown name (beginning with K?). That latter place is *the same* as the place where they moved from (col. 9). I *think*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Johan is born in *Korsør*, Thora in *Vallø By*, Karen & Kai in *Kjøbenh.*(-avn) = Copenhagen, Per in *Hellerup* (and Yelva in *Aarhus*).

Comment: Thanks. The 1901 that I found later had Thora in Valløby, so that's fine. It also had Karen and Kaj born in Kjøbenhavn and that I didn't understand because whatever the 1906 stated, it wasn't Kjøbenhavn. But now, from what you've told me, I can see that it's simply(?) an abbreviation for Kjøbenhavn. And yes, it's where they moved from as well.

Comment: Yes, it's simply an abbreviation. Other common ones are Kbh, Kbhvn, Kjbhvn, Kjøb, Kjøbh, etc.